# Continuous Delivery, PaaS and Infrastructure Automation

Tags: jenkins, cloud, cloud-foundry, infrastructure, continuous-delivery

I am reading about the topics continuous integration and continuous delivery (CD) with Jenkins. 
Obv if you want to do CD, you have to automate your deployment process to QA and P. I read a lot about infrastructure automation and infrastructure as code with chef/puppet/docker, which is necessary for doing CD.

My question: What if i am hosting my app on the cloud (i. e. i am using some Cloud foundry infrastructure like AWS or Azure), which automates my infrastructure by itself(or?). But how is it possible to follow infrastructure as code on AWS? or is it even necessary?

I mean, if you host your application by yourself, you obv have to realise infrastructure automation to do CD, but on the cloud it is given already?!

I hope you understand my "question"

Answer (score 2):

That depends entirely on the infrastructure architecture of your solution. Specially on the kind of service (from the cloud foundry infrastructure) you're using.

For example, if you use EC2 servers from AWS to deploy your web applications, is perfectly plausible to use Jenkins + Chef or Puppet to continuously deploy that app. Since you have more granular configurations to perform. You can implement infrastructure as code from jenkins pipelines all the way down to server provisioning, choosing AMI for deploying new instances an stuff like that. You'll have more configuration overhead but also more control of whats happening and how it's happening.

But If you're using a PaaS approach, such as Elastic Beanstalk service from AWS, the deployment process is more transparent, I would not feel the necessity of using such tools, just a job with a step to acquire the new pre-built version artefact and another step with a command line interface trigger to update a new versions would suffice. But it's not impeditive of using IaC in such occasions.

Comment: thx a lot, this helps me a lot! So PaaS doing deployment automation easy and Straight forward, but on the Other hand, you cannot customize it!

Comment: @Maermot consider at least upvoting my answer if it helped you. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Continuous integration meaning every commit in your repository should be build and deployed to the integration/dev environment automatically. If there is a compile time error or your unit test cases are failing, it shouldn't be deployed to the integration environment and at the same time your team should get a notification about build failure with a log. If you are not able to achieve these from your cloud provider you should use Jenkins and CM tools. In short CI/CD is just a concept. you can implement it by using Jenkins, CM tools OR you can write your custom scripts OR you can leverage Cloud services. You can choose any of these but make sure you follow all the CI/CD best practices.

Thanks - KS